# Conditional Expectation v.s. a new Random Variable

Tags: probability

I am wondering if the following situation is trivial for you guys. For me, it is not. For the book, it is trivial.

**Example**: **You write a software program over and over, and each time there is probability $p$ that it works correctly, independent of previous attempts. What is the mean and variance of $X$, the number of tries until the program works correctly?**

Clearly $X$ has geometric distribution with PMF  $\:\:\:p_X(k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p, k=1,2,...$
Then $E[X]=\sum_{1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}p$. We can go ahead and compute this series directly (I did computed it,) or we can use conditioning because we have the following formula
$$E[X]=\sum_{i=}E[X|A_i]P(A_i)$$
where $A_i's$ is a disjoint partition of the sample space. So, let $A_1=\{X=1\}$ and $A_2=\{X>1\}$. Clearly $P(A_1)=p$ and $P(A_2)=1-p$. Then $$E[X]=E[X|X=1]P(X=1)+E[X|X>1]P(X>1)=1\cdot p+(1-p)E[X|X>1].$$
**Here is where it got me thinking. In the book, it argues like this. Given that $\{X>1\}$, i.e., the first try fails, we have wasted one try, and we are back to where we start, thus, 
$$E[X|X>1]=1+E[X].$$**
Even though it does make sense, it is not rigorous, and I had to work it out like this to see why the above equality is true.

$E[X|X>1]=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\frac{P(\{X=k\}\cap \{X>1\})}{P(X>1)}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k\frac{(1-p)^{k-1}p}{1-p}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-2}p=$
$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(k+1)(1-p)^{k-1}p=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}p+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p=$

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:=E[X]+1$

since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k-1}p=1.$

Well, I verified it, but I still couldn't see why the book's argument is believable.

Comment: It is virtually the same argument as the following : No matter how many throws of a dice failed to be a $6$, you need in the average $6$ additional throws to get a $6$.

Comment: Observe that for any nonnegative integers $j,k$ 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X > j + k \mid X > k) &= \frac{\mathbb P(X>j+k,X>k)}{\mathbb P(X>k)}\\
&= \frac{(1-p)^{j+k}}{(1-p)^k}\\
&= (1-p)^j\\
&= \mathbb P(X>j).
\end{align}
That is, the geometric distribution has the *memoryless* property.

Comment: Moreover, $$ \mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X>k).$$

Answer (score 1):

As remarked both in the question and in the comments, the formula can be verified in multiple ways. I try to give a proof that gives perhaps a simpler intuition.

We can assume that $X=\min\{n\ge 1: Y_n=1\} $
where $(Y_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of a i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with success parameter $p$. 
Now, let 
$X'=\min\{n\ge 1: Y_{n+1}=1\} $
and observe that
$$
X = X' + 1
$$
provided that $X>1$.
We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X|X>1] = \mathbb{E}[X' + 1|B_1=0] = 1+ \mathbb{E}[X'] = 1 + \mathbb{E}[X]
\end{align}
where in the second equality I used that $X'$ does not depend on $B_1$ and in the last I used that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X']$.